# Translating a query from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a legacy query from years ago that was written for an MS Access backend:

```
    DELETE category.*
    FROM category
    LEFT JOIN product_category ON category.id = product_category.categoryid
    WHERE product_category.categoryid IS NULL
      AND category.id IN
        (SELECT cat.id
         FROM category AS cat
         LEFT JOIN category AS cat_par ON cat_par.category_parent = cat.id
         WHERE cat_par.category_parent IS NULL
           AND cat.category_parent != 0
           AND cat.link IS NULL);
```

My system was changed to SQL Server and this query no longer runs.
I have tested the subquery (in the parenthesis) separately and that works as expected. Just no records are getting deleted.

I have tried changing  the first two lines to read `DELETE FROM category` (the only syntax difference I was able to look up) but still no deletion occurs.

Comment: Try `DELETE` category instead of `DELETE category.*`.

Comment: What do you mean **No longer runs**. What happens when you try to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Binaya Regmi is correct. When deleting in SQL-Server explicitly name the table you want to delete the rows from - especially necessary when using a join.

So in your case change the top row from

```
DELETE category.*
```

to

```
DELETE category
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I've always felt that syntax to be a little un-intuitive.

Comment: @StevePettifer you can make it perhaps more intuituve by supplying the optional `FROM`: `DELETE FROM category` etc

Comment: @AakashM That's not the point I was making: I meant I never understood why Access used `tablename.*` given the `.*` is redundant yet intuitively sort of makes sense to a lot of beginners thanks to `SELECT *`. But anyway, the OP got their answer and everyone's a winner.